# Can't solve this sequence number puzzle

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

[image]

Im almost about to give up with this, So my answers were 1311 and 1221, but both are wrong, can't manage to see other logical solution hehe.

first one is because I though it was sequence where you add 1 after placing ones on the sides, but its not correct, second answer is because I replaced 11 for 21, but also wrong, any ideas?

Comment: This is a pretty well known puzzle, one that it doesn't seem like you created. Can you specify where you found it?

Comment: @PartyHatPanda I saw it on an instagram history and its been on my head since yesterday lol

Comment: I don't know the procedure on best practices to answer questions that were not created by the user... moderators, thoughts?

Comment: @PartyHatPanda Ah, you found it! Well, I've already answered now :-/ and can't delete my answer as it's accepted.

Comment: You can find this on the OEIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next one is

> 111221

because each line is

> *describing* the line before it.

Read it like this:

> 1
>  11 (one one)
>  21 (two ones)
>  1211 (one two, one one)
>  111221 (one one, one two, two ones)
>  ...

Comment: @MacGyver88 If you're good with things that *don't* match, I won't recommend you to [these puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matches) :-)

Comment: Good one.......